# ORA - 31011 when exporting to XLS

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I am running the following query

```
Select PhotoNumber, extract(xmltype(photoinfo,1), '/DataIM/PhotoChosen/Photo/jpg[1]/text()') "photoinfo" From ProfilePictures Where photosourcetype = 10
```

It works fine and gives me results without error but when i export the result to xls from Oracle sql developer
It gives me the following error

```
Ora-31011 xml parsing failed
Ora- 19213 error occured in xml processing at lines 40
Lpx-00216 invalid character 226(0xE2)
ORA - 06512 at sys.xmltype, line 283
Ora - 06512 at line 1
```

I have used xmltype to export the result of that xml column into excel sheet

When i went to line 40 my xml was

```
<DataIM>
<Section>1</Section>
<PhotoChosen>
      <Photo>
          <jpg>me &amp; MyPic</jpg>
       </Photo>
    </PhotoChosen>
</DataIM>
```

At line 283, everything was same except in jpg node it was

```
<jpg>my cat (3 times)</jpg>
```

I feel that these errors are due to the & and (), but why are they occurring when i try to export the result to xls?

Comment: The line numbers are PL/SQL code references, not lines within your XML. The error refers to "character 226(0xE2)", [which is 'â'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e2/index.htm). So, this looks like it's probably a character set issue. You are still using `1` as the CSID in the XMLType() call, but your BLOB has non-ASCII characters. As I said on your previous questions, you need to use the correct character set; does it work with `0` (DB character set) or UTF-8? (I also mentioned that extract is deprecated...)

Comment: @AlexPoole when i tried with xml query, all the text was underlined red. Although the query ran but it was all red underlined.

Comment: Well, that's a side issue really; and sounds like you might just be using a really old client. (Current SQL Developer etc. shouldn't have a problem with it.) The errors aren't because of extract; they're from the character set. You might want to include *how* you're exporting the result to Excel.